# Spring data cassandra - Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession': Invocation of init method failed

Tags: cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I am trying to used Spring Data Cassandra

I am getting the following error as shown in the stack trace, while using Spring Data Cassandra. \
Could you help with this error

My pom.xml is like so..

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.sap.icn</groupId>
  <artifactId>sample-cassandra-data</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>sample-cassandra-data</name>

    <properties>
        <spring.framework.version>3.2.8.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
    </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RC1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Stacktrace:

```
2016-05-20 20:04:42 INFO  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext:578 - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1324409e: startup date [Fri May 20 20:04:42 SGT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-05-20 20:04:42 INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader:317 - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [application-context.xml]
2016-05-20 20:04:43 INFO  PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer:172 - Loading properties file from class path resource [cassandra.properties]
2016-05-20 20:04:43 WARN  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext:546 - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/util/concurrent/EventExecutor
2016-05-20 20:04:43 WARN  DisposableBeanAdapter:271 - Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'cassandraCluster': java.lang.NullPointerException
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.158 sec <<< FAILURE!
testTxnSave(com.sap.icn.yaas.recommender.data.TransactionTest)  Time elapsed: 1.076 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/util/concurrent/EventExecutor
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.sap.icn.yaas.recommender.data.TransactionTest.setUp(TransactionTest.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/util/concurrent/EventExecutor
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1286)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:159)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:249)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:282)
    at org.springframework.cassandra.config.CassandraCqlSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CassandraCqlSessionFactoryBean.java:82)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CassandraSessionFactoryBean.java:43)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.util.concurrent.EventExecutor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 50 more
```

Answer (score 6):

Change your Spring Data Cassandra dependency to...

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

The `1.4.1.RELEASE` is the most current, up-to-date version of [Spring Data Cassandra](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-cassandra/) now.

Also, you need to declare an explicit dependency on [Netty](http://netty.io/), which is used by the DataStax Cassandra driver's I/O subsystem (when communicating to Cassandra asynchronously).  The DataStax Cassandra driver is [used](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/blob/1.4.1.RELEASE/pom.xml#L36) by SD Cassandra.

The dependency is...

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
  <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.36.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Finally, I am not certain your core **Spring Framework** version property is doing a whole lot in your Maven POM file...

```
    <spring.framework.version>3.2.8.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
```

...as it does not seem to be used anywhere, but you should be aware that SD Cassandra **1.4** is built on core Spring Framework `4.2.5.RELEASE`.

You can determine this by following the SD Cassandra (parent) POM hierarchy starting [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/blob/1.4.1.RELEASE/pom.xml#L17-L19), then [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-build/blob/1.8.1.RELEASE/parent/pom.xml#L106) (along with [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-build/blob/1.8.1.RELEASE/parent/pom.xml#L543-L553)).  You can take a look at the core Spring Framework [BOM](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cspring-framework-bom) file to see all that it pulls in.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: Declaring an explicit dependency on Netty solved the issue for me (though I'm not sure why because I used SD Cassandra in another Maven project before without the need to explicitly declaring an dependency on Netty). Thank you anyway.